# Can searching for overlapping elements from one array in a two-dimensional array be simplified to avoid nested for loops?

Tags: javascript, big-o

I have an array of items that I would like to remove from within a nested object array, if present.

```
var itemsToRemove = [1, 2, 3];

var data = [
    { id: 'a', list: [1, 3, 4, 5] },
    { id: 'b', list: [2, 6, 7] }
];
```

should update to

```
data = [
    { id: 'a', list: [4, 5] },
    { id: 'b', list: [6, 7] }
];
```

I am able to cut it down to two loops (below) instead of three, but I'm wondering if there's any way to simplify it to one loop/unnested loops.

```
data.forEach(obj => {
    var map = {};
    obj.list.forEach(el => map[el] = true);
    itemsToRemove.forEach(el => if(map[el] { delete map[el] }));
    obj.list = Object.keys(map);
});
```

Comment: Are the arrays sorted? If so you can improve the algorithm significantly.

Comment: The arrays wouldn't be sorted. In my case, the values in list aren't actually numbers, they they are objects that contain some number id, but decided to simplify it for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const
    itemsToRemove = [1, 2, 3],
    data = [
        { id: 'a', list: [1, 3, 4, 5] },
        { id: 'b', list: [2, 6, 7] }
    ];

data.forEach(o => o.list = o.list.filter(v => !itemsToRemove.includes(v)));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you need a more faster approach, you could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
const
    itemsToRemove = [1, 2, 3],
    data = [
        { id: 'a', list: [1, 3, 4, 5] },
        { id: 'b', list: [2, 6, 7] }
    ],
    remove = new Set(itemsToRemove);

data.forEach(o => o.list = o.list.filter(v => !remove.has(v)));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think the first approach has 3 nested loops (forEach, filter, includes) while the second brings it down to two (forEach, filter).